Assigning a value to a 2-dimentional associative array in bash is not working
I have a two dimentional array in bash and i want to checnge the value of one place in it and it doesn't work.
I tried doing:
chessboard[""$number4", "$number3""]="${chessboard[""$number2", "$number1""]}"
chessboard["$number2, $number1"]="."

but it doesn't work.
The matrix was declared like that:
declare -A chessboard

I cehckd and number1, number2, number3, number4 all holds that right value, which i got by doing this:
first_letter=$(echo "${array_of_moves[j]}" | cut -c 1) 
ascii_value1=$(printf "%d" "'$first_letter")
number1=$((ascii_value1 - 96))

to all of the numbers, but when Iprint the value I get no change.

Your quoting is all wrong. Why do you have two double-quotes?

Bash doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays.

Get rid of the excess quotes: chessboard["$number4, $number3"]

But be aware that x=3; y=7; chessboard["$x, $y"] is identical to foo='3, 7'; chessboard["$foo"] - it is NOT a 2-dimensional array, it's a 1-dimensional array with a concatenated index and if you want to use that as a pseudo-2-dimensional array like POSIX awk has, I'd strongly recommend you find some character other than , to separate the index substrings, e.g. at least $'\n' or something more exotic.

please review create a minimal, reproducible example then come back and update the question; in particular: show the contents of all vairables (eg, complete output from typeset -p array_of_moves chessboard number1 number2 number3 number4), an explanation of what you mean by it doesn't work (error? wrong results? something else?), and include the expected results of your operation

bash doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays natively.
But you can use hash array in this way to create an array of two-characters hashes:
x="1", y="1"; declare -A array; array["$x$y"]=something
it will works fine until x and y will be a single number/character because for bash it will not be two separate indixes, but a single string (hash index)
